# Enviar CTRL+V via PostMessage

Tags: delphi

Olá, preciso enviar a combinação de cliques CTRL + V via POSTMESSAGE. Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
 PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_CONTROL,0);
 PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_V,0); (Ele da erro nessa linha diz que o VK_V não existe)
 PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_CONTROL,1);
 PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_V,1);
```

O que posso estar fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso ao enviar a mensagem [`WM_PASTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649028(VS.85).aspx) para a *handle* da janela assim:

```pascal
var
  appHandle: HWND;
begin
 appHandle := FindWindow(nil, 'TitulodaJanela');
 if appHandle = 0 then // Se não encontrou a janela
   exit; 
 PostMessage(appHandle, WM_PASTE, 0, 0);
```

Comment: eu testei dessa forma, ele não cola....se eu der CTRL + V ele cola certinho, mais com POSTMESSAGE não vai...alguma outra sugestão ?

Comment: não sei porque, o segundo comando, ele aparece a letra V do outro lado...porque será ? e não cola...

Comment: ok @Sunstreaker, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Tenho sim @Sunstreaker, até porque se eu der um CTRL + V na máquina ele cola normal..estranho né ?

Comment: deu certo sim...o Handle estava errado! Obrigado amigo!

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [**o site do MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), não existe uma constante para as teclas alfabéticas, sendo assim use diretamente o valor em hexadecimal.

No caso, para simular o pressionamento da tecla V use o valor 0x56.

Comment: então ficaria dessa forma:      PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_CONTROL,1);
PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,56,1); Fiz desse jeito ele aparece o número 8 na tela ja viu isso ? rsrsrss

Comment: @user7605 você escreveu o número como decimal, deve colocar `0x` na frente, que significa que você está passando como hexadecimal; 56 em decimal corresponde a 0x38, que é valor correspondente a Virtual Key da tecla 8.

Comment: se eu colocar PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,0x56,1); ele não aceita, da erro.

Comment: @user7605 Eu não entendi bem o que você pretende com a sua aplicação, talvez o erro não esteja nessa função em específico, de qualquer forma, nos dê mais detalhes do erro ocorrido. Alternativamente se quiser testar com o número 0x56 representado em decimal coloque `PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,86,1);`

Comment: é uma aplicação remota, em que os funcionários conectam em um servidor através de socket. Eu fiz dessa forma:      PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_CONTROL,1);
     PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,86,1); Ao invés de dar CTRL + V no sistema, ele ta aparecendo a letra "v" rsrsrsrs...

Comment: @user7605 na sua pergunta você colocou  `PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_CONTROL,0);` vindo antes, agora no comentário você pôs `PostMessage(h,WM_KEYDOWN,VK_CONTROL,1);` vindo antes. Não tenho como usar uma IDE agora para testar, mas vc não acha que inverteu quando o CTRL é pressionado e liberado?

Comment: obrigado pelo empenho....eu também achei que fosse isso, arrumei agora e mesmo assim ele insere 2x a letra V...eu vi um comando na NET que diz para usar o seguinte: PostMessage(AHWND, WM_PASTE, 0, 0);, mesmo assim ele não da certo.